# Фиксированная нижняя граница при увеличении высоты блока

Tags: javascript, css

На странице в самом низу есть блок. При клике на него его высота увеличивается. Но прокрутка страницы остается на месте, а блок увеличивается вниз.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="block" id="open_block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Примерно так: https://jsfiddle.net/b6wd5s4m/

Как сделать так, чтобы при раскрытии блока его нижняя граница была зафиксирована и оставалась у нижней границы экрана, а страница как бы прокручивалась вниз?

Comment: абсолютное позиционирвоание https://jsfiddle.net/b6wd5s4m/1/

Comment: @Jean-Claude Это не совсем то что нужно. Так блок всегда будет у нижней границы экрана. А он должен быть в низу страницы, а не экрана и перематываться как не фиксированый блок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда так, доки
- https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates
- https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window

```js
var open_block = document.getElementById('open_block');

open_block.addEventListener('click', function() {
  open_block.classList.toggle('open_block');
  var bot = open_block.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  window.scrollTo(0, bot);
});
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #04a513;
  transparent: 1s;
}
.open_block {
  height: 300px;
  transparent: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="block" id="open_block">

  </div>
</div>
```